# Excel: Return top 5 to seperate page

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that calculates the monthly reception of material. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to get the top 5 results for Stock listed on a separate page, and also Nonstock listed on the same separate page. Each should have the MaterialCode and Total Cost column. It should look like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! The data will be updated from month to month so the top 5 is bound to change.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into using [`Rank()`](http://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-rank.html)? Perhaps with `Index/Match`.

Comment: Use Large(IF()) array formula.

Answer (score 1):

If it can be reasonably assumed that the amounts (... in column B?) will not be duplicated to the penny then use the following to get the largest 'non-stock' amount in F4 and the associated material code in E4.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )))/(C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,B:B ))=$E$3), ROW(1:1))   '◄ F4
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(F4,B:B, 0))    '◄ E4
```

Fill down as necessary to retrieve the sequentially ranked numbers. Adust formula for the 'stock' items.

[image]